# Synchronized JList and JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Synchronized JList and JComboBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939563/synchronized-jlist-and-jcombobox)

Hello,

In Java Swing, what's the best way for a JList and a JComboBox to be synchronized in terms of the data, i.e., to have the same list of items at any given point of time? Basically, if I add items to (or remove items from) one, the other should reflect the change automatically.
I've tried doing the following, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
JList list = new JList();
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
// add items to listModel...
list.setModel(listModel);
comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(listModel.toArray()));
```

Answer (score 3):

You're creating two models in your code.  When you construct the new DefaultComboBoxModel by passing in the listModel contents you are constructing a second model that just starts with the same contents as the first.  They won't update the same.  You want the two components to share a model.  In other words...

```
JList list = new JList();
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
DefaultComboBoxModel listModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
// add items to listModel...
list.setModel(listModel);
comboBox.setModel(listModel);
```